# Error running 'pod install' (Flutter VS Code) - Adapty SDK

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I get the following error whenever I try to build to device or run pod install.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Adapty":
  In Podfile:
    adapty_flutter (from .symlinks/plugins/adapty_flutter/ios) was resolved to 2.9.3, which depends on
      Adapty (= 2.9.6)

    adapty_ui_flutter (from .symlinks/plugins/adapty_ui_flutter/ios) was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      AdaptyUI (= 2.0.2) was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
        Adapty (~> 2.7.0)
```

I am running the latest version of flutter and VS Code. I've tried cleaning, pod upgrade, repo upgrade, too many things to mention and nothing is working. My pubspec.yaml looks like this...

```
adapty_flutter: ^2.9.0
adapty_ui_flutter: ^2.0.6
```

I've been at this for hours and think it is a problem with Adapty but need to get it fixed. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please do first clear DerivedData and then flutter clean and then run flutter pub get and then pod install

Comment: @HardikMehta can you explain what you mean by "clear DerivedData"? What are the steps for this? Thank you!

Comment: When you open xcode  it has preference in menu you can open that and goto location where you can find derivedData.

Comment: I'm running into this too.  Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this too, it seems the UI package is slightly outdated.

As a workaround, in my pubspec.yaml I set

```
adapty_flutter: 2.7.1
```

That works with version 2.0.6 of adapty_ui_flutter.

Not ideal, but until adapty_ui_flutter is updated not much else we can do.

Comment: You are correct. This was the only thing that worked for me as well. I had to go through the entire process of "completely" removing a Flutter package before it would work. 

https://saxenapushpam.medium.com/removing-a-flutter-package-step-by-step-guide-6abdf02edb34

Just updating the pubspec.yaml was not enough. Thanks for confirming as much on your end. Hopefully Adapty gets their house in order soon.